# Grab 2 words from end of line

Tags: regex

I have a `file list` of subdomain and i want to only grab the domain name which is 2 word from the end of line separated with `.` delimiter. Illustration:

```
blog.clova.line.me
to
line.me
```

From the illustration, I performed below command to strip subdomain

```
cut -d "." -f "2-3"
```

Above command only works for 3 deep subdomain and would result in: only getting the middle string if it's more than 3+ deep-length.

```
clova.line.me -> line.me
blog.clova.line.me -> clova.line
```

So I had to use shell scripting which look like this:

```
while read -r line; do for $(tr -cd "." << ${line} | wc -c) in i; if $i == 2; do cut -d "." -f "2-3"; else if $i == 3; do cut -d "." - f "3-4"
  
and so-on
```

I though this is not efficient as it's checking each time if a line has numbers of `.` character. I tried to use regex:

```
([a-z]*)\.([a-z]*)$
```

The above regex doesn't work, especially if the domain has special-char in between.

```
mobile.amazon-aws.com --> aws.com
branch.line-dev.net --> dev.net
git.line-apps-dev.net --> dev.net
yugioh.line-games-de-dev.net > dev.net
```

As summary:

- Subdomain can be 3+ deep length
- Domain can be separated with 1+ : `-` character
- `target` : Grab domain from subdomain list with rules above

Any help would be cherished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply include the character `-` in your regex `([a-z-]*)\.([a-z]*)$`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Yn9Aqm/1

---

Alternative: You might want to tokenize the string by dots instead. Then picking the last 2 items of the array. That is easier than using a regex.

Comment: Ah, Thank You. I tought it was restricted to ```[a-z]``` or ```[0-9]``` only.